# calculation with conditional probabilities

Tags: probability

I am reading one statistics book and somehow I do not understand how the derived this answer: 
[image]

If we summarize over c how do we get P(b|a)?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be true.  Take an extreme case, where there is only one value of $c$ and it represents the whole space, i.e. $p(c)=1$.  Trivially then, $c$ is independent from both $a$ and $b$.  You have then $p(a)p(c|a)p(b|c)=p(a)\cdot 1\cdot p(b) = p(a)\cdot p(b)$.  Comparing this to the r.h.s., you see $p(a)p(b)=p(a)p(b|a)$.  Assuming $p(a)>0$, you have $p(b)=p(b|a)$, which is not always true.  (It is true *if and only if* $a$ and $b$ are independent).

Comment: Agreed.  What book did you see this in?

Comment: The question of what conditions *will* make this true., it seems if $a,b,c$ are all mutually independent for all $c$, and if the collection of $c$'s form a partition of the space, that it will be true, but in that case, why would they bother using conditional probabilities?

Comment: You ought to include the other conditions otherwise this question will be considered off-topic for its missing content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the book I would assume it meant either:

- either something like $$\displaystyle P(A=a)\sum_c P(C=c \mid A=a) P(B=b\mid A=a, C=c) = P(A=a)P(B=b\mid A=a),$$
- or that any relationship between $A$ and $B$ depends solely on the value of $C$ i.e. $$P(B=b\mid A=a, C=c) = P(B=b\mid C=c).$$